# How to find the table record difference after changing the ROW_FORMAT of mysql table

Tags: mysql-8.0, mysql-5.6

I want to migrate from mysql 5.6 to mysql 8 but got some warning related with **maximum allowed size (8126) for a record on index leaf page.**

so need to confirm whether data are safe after changing the row format. initilay tried with checksum but checksum also differs for few of the tables if we change the row format.so is there any other way to match the table records before and after changing row format and even after migration.